# ScrollView not working after reload view swift 3

Tags: ios, view, swift3, uiscrollview

I'd like to reload my `View` but after I reload it my `ScrollView` not working, but everything else refresh correctly. Here is my code to refresh view:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func reloadViewFromNib() {
        let parent = view.superview
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        view = nil
        parent?.addSubview(view) // This line causes the view to be reloaded
    }
}
```

I tried to put these into my `viewDidLoad` maybe I just need to refresh the `SrollView` manually but it's still not working.

```
self.beSrcollView.bounces = true
self.beSrcollView.delegate = self
self.beSrcollView.updateConstraints()
self.beSrcollView.isScrollEnabled = true
self.beSrcollView.updateFocusIfNeeded()
self.beSrcollView.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
self.beSrcollView.needsUpdateConstraints()
```

Have you any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: I'd to reload my whole view to be like the first time I opened it. The textfields be empty etc.

Comment: then this method wont works . you need to do empty textfield manually using loop .

Comment: This method works fine for everything except the ScrollView.

Comment: how to expect that scrollview . which kind of view exists on scrollview ?

Comment: do you mean that your scrollview has stopped scrolling? 
If thats the case you need to check your scrollviews content size

Comment: The scrollview contains a basic View which contains buttons,textfields,stackviews etc. When I run this method everything reloaded and take their defult state but scrollview become disabled.

Comment: Lalit kumar's solution works fine! Thank you for effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    self.beSrcollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000) // height change according 
}
```

Comment: @Always Welcome mate

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
scrollView.reloadInputViews()
```